# How do I allow users to display LinkedIn profiles on my site?

Tags: linkedin-api

I have a site (using PHP and JavaScript with jQuery) which allows users to display a profile, and I would like them to have the option of simply importing their LinkedIn profile, if they have one, rather than having to type everything in again.

I'm not sure what the best approach is here... I've read some of the LinkedIn API documentation, but I'm not even really sure which bit I need to look at.

The process should be:

- User goes to profile management page
- User is shown a checkbox saying "use my LinkedIn profile", and a textarea.  If they don't want to type their profile into the checkbox, they check the checkbox, and somehow their Linked In profile is retrieved.
- The LinkedIn profile is stored (or some kind of id is stored), so that the profile can be retrieved by anyone else at any time.

I'm not very familiar with the LinkedIn API, or with the site itself, so I'm not even sure what's possible.  Does this sound possible, and if so, where do I start?

Comment: That all sounds very possible. I suggest you start by looking at http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sign-linkedin

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the User Profile tutorial here:
http://developer.linkedinlabs.com/tutorials/jsapi_profile/

The example uses jquery so it should be pretty easy for you to extend this to do what you want.